# D3 orgchart - displaying user details

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Based on answers to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926539/organization-chart-tree-online-dynamic-collapsible-pictures-in-d3), I was able to create a company organization chart code that currently looks like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/i5T1vbEH7cTjzKmG6wo6?p=preview)

I'd like to display additional user details like email, phone, photo etc. (which are embedded in the abc2.json file) in column to right under search bar, [as such](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbk2Y.png)

Here is a [similar orgchart](http://robinl.github.io/d3_orgchart_yammer/website/) except I want details displayed to right of chart not below.
Also, instead of displaying details on mouse-hover, I need it to differentiate between clicking on user (to display details) vs clicking on node (to expand children).

How to do this ?

```
Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a group for the texts appended to the node, add click listener to this group and stop event propagation after populating the details:

```
var texts = nodeEnter.append('g')
            .on("click", userClick);
  // name
  texts.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".30em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // title
  texts.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", "1.5em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.title; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);



function userClick(d) {
    $('#details').show();
    $('.name').text(d.name);
    $('.email').text(d.email);
    $('.phone').text(d.phone);
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Here is your updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FQCegRgUGtqizwPRLBMP

Comment: That is great !  I see that once I click on details, it 'pushes' the chart down - see http://imgur.com/a/MMi2S - is it possible to decouple or disconnect the details 'frame' from the chart (maybe somehow in the css style) so they're displayed independently ? And is it also possible to display the user details when I search for them in search bar ?

Comment: yes, that can handled with css. Give it a try, there can be many possible solutions, try reducing the width of svg of example.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Do you know how to make photo appear in details section ? If the json file contains image file name, can I add $('.photo').image(d.photo) property in the userClick function ?

Comment: i have a few more requirements.. would you be interested in working on this project for money, or gift cards ? i can send $50 worth amazon gc, paypal, bitcoin etc. I can pay first if that would make you comfortable.