# SVG sprite image inside <image>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, d3.js

In my project i am using one `<image>`  inside `<svg>` to load image inside one circle i have referred bellow link

[SVG image inside circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442833/svg-image-inside-circle)

its working fine and they are using .png image, but i want to give one .svg(sprite image) so when i tried bellow code the full sprite image is loading, how i will show a single image from that sprite image.

In my same project i used sprite image with `<div>` like this

```
 background: url('../../Images/slice_01.svg') 38% 16%/ 488px 79px no-repeat;
```

with  its working fine because by using bellow portion

38% 16%/ 488px 79px no-repeat

we can show single image from that sprite but in `<image>` there is href  is present instead of url  so i tried

```
.attr("href", "http://localhost:62706/Images/slice_01.svg");
```

like this it will load that full image but where i will give this position in `<href>` to show a particular image.

If there is any solution for this???

My sprite image is slice_01.svg

[image]

My design is

```
<svg id="graph" width="100%" height="400px">
<defs>
<pattern id="image" x="0%" y="0%" height="100%" width="100%"
         viewBox="0 0 512 512">
<image href="http://localhost:62706/Images/slice_01.svg" x="0%" y="0%" width="512" height="512" ></image>
</pattern>
 </defs>  
<circle id="sd" class="medium" cx="5%" cy="40%" r="5%" fill="url(#image)"   stroke="lightblue" stroke-width="0.5%" />
</svg>
```

here the problem is it will load that full image.From that i want to give position values to show a particular image(like i did with `<div>`).But in `<href>` we cant give that position.

Comment: How is your `svg` defined?  I would recommend doing something [like this](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/), where each sprit is a `g` in your svg with a unique id, you load the svg once and then your href becomes `.attr("href", "#id-of-your-g-sprite"); `

Comment: @Mark
Thanks for the reply..But in that example each image are separate but in my case a single image is the combination of more than one images that's why in <div> we are using some positions  like
38% 16%/ 488px 79px no-repeat  
but in <href> if i use like this it will affect the url and we will not get image.

Comment: @Mark: I added my sprite image in the question that is a single image from that i want to use position system to show a particular pic

Comment: That's a PNG of your SVG, can you include in your question the SVG itself?  Open it in a text editor and cut/paste it into your question.

Comment: @Mark :I am  sorry i edited that question 2 days before i forgot to remind you, I added my design please check